# Accessing function from within another with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm trying to get the [jquery loadmask](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/) addon to work that will mask elements (for loading content). I'm using knockout.js, and when if I mask an element outside of my viewmodel it works, but I want to mask it upon submitting a POST request, and then unmask when I receive it. I'm getting an "object has no method mask" error from this. I'm not quite sure how to go about setting up an object to access it.

This works, but it's not what I want. I noted in the code where I would like to call mask from

```
<div id = "register_container">
    <div data-bind="visible: register()">
          <div id = "register_form"> <!--this is the div I want to mask -->>
              <button data-bind="click: submitRegistration">Submit</button>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>

function MyViewModel(){

     self.submitRegistration = function(){
           //I want to mask here. When I try it says Object[object object] has no method mask
            $.post....{
                if(data.result == success){
                     // andunmask here
                }
            }
      }
}

$("#register_form").mask("Waiting...");  //the masking works when I place it here, but it's always enabled and I want it inside the viewmodel where I noted so it only works when the POST request is in process
```

That's great and all, but I want to mask something from inside the viewmodel where I noted. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I see several things that could be the problem.

Frist, you're doing assignment as opposed to comparison in the `if` statement. Use this instead:

```
if(data.result == success){
```

or even

```
if(data.result === success){
```

Second is the fact that I don't quite understand your code `self.submitRegistration(){`, which typically looks more like this:

```
var MyViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.submitRegistration = function() {
    };
};
```

Then, if I mock the `$.post` call, it would work like this:

```
var MyViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.register = ko.observable(true);

    self.submitRegistration = function() {
        $("#register_form").mask("Waiting...");

        // Mock $.post
        window.setTimeout(function () {

            if (1 == 1) {
                // andunmask here
                $("#register_form").unmask();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQcW4/) for a demo.

You could even have Knockout help you find the element to look for:

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQcW4/1/) for a demo of that.

```
    // Use the "event" parameter to find the element...
    self.submitRegistration = function(data, event) {
        $(event.target).closest('#register_form').mask("Waiting...");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll take a look. The viewmodel is just pseudocode so any inaccuracies are nothing. I quickly typed it up so I didn't have to chop up a hundred something lines of code on here.

Comment: Hmm, you'll get better help (and happier volunteering strangers) if you make sure your question's not "quickly typed up" mate, make sure the code you post is syntactically okay and all. Now *I* had to go through it trying to help you while you *knew* it wasn't quite okay :'(. Not cool...

Comment: @Joroen I'm sorry, but I don't see how that changes anything. I had a few syntax errors, but that doesn't change where or how I'm trying to access the mask() function. From a functionality point of view, it's the same.

Comment: @user1406951 I just thought it rude that you didn't take the time to create a neat repro, but instead just *knowingly* let us waste *our* time working around it.